# React-Redux-Form component testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-redux-form

I am using [React-Redux-Form](https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form) and [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) on client side of application.

I'm stuck on how to test my components. I have made a small project [on github](https://github.com/DmitryIvanovIAMM/react-redux-form-login-test) with one of my components named `LoginModal`.

To start testing, I am following [this tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/vijayst/unit-testing-react-components-jest-or-enzyme-du1087lh8), but when I try to `.find()` something in my rendered component, the result is an `array` of `length` zero. I  am expecting that `login.find(Button)` returns an `object` that I can then call `myRenderedComponent.find(Button).simulate('click')` or something else.

One acceptable result is `login.find(LoginModal)`, but the deepest exploration of it also gives no result. Your advice, please.

Comment: Did you try looking at the tests in React-Redux-Form itself?

Comment: Yes, I do. But this not helps. There are no example how to test nested components. F.e. here  https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form/blob/master/test/form-component-spec.js to test input fields on form it used <input type="text" /> code, even not <Control.text /> introduced in React-Redux-Form. I don't understand why after component rendering with mount() I can't find f.e. input in nested component.